# Record Sound in Android using ActionScript 3

Tags: android, actionscript-3, record

i build a application that record sound in Desktop using ActionScript 3 , now i convert the application to Andriod Application but there is a problem that SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA event doesn't receive any data to record 
Here is the code :

```
private var _microphone:Microphone;
private var _buffer:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
private var _difference:uint;

public function record():void
{
    if ( _microphone == null )
        _microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone();

    _difference = getTimer();
    _microphone.setSilenceLevel(_silenceLevel, _timeOut);
    _microphone.gain = _gain;
    _microphone.rate = _rate;
    _buffer.length = 0;
    _microphone.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, onSampleData);
    _microphone.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, onStatus);
} 

private function onSampleData(event:SampleDataEvent):void
{
    _recordingEvent.time = getTimer() - _difference;
    dispatchEvent( _recordingEvent );
    var buteData:Number;
    while(event.data.bytesAvailable > 0)
    {
        buteData = event.data.readFloat();
        _buffer.writeFloat(buteData);
        soundBytes.writeFloat( buteData);
}
}
```

anyone can help here 
Thanx

Comment: Do you request for the _android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO_  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f-5d0f4f25128cc9cd0cb-7ffc.html in application manifestAdditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, maybe you don't check out about AIR for Android settings. If you not checked in the RECORD_AUDIO. you should check it.

refer a below image.

[image]

Comment: thanks , i want to ask about output of recording sound , the output is .wav , if i need to convert it to .mp3 it will take time of converting specially on Android will take more time , this is not good , is there any way to record sound as mp3 ?

Comment: See a http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952395/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-mp3-using-aspx-script-from-flash-as3-0/11953512#11953512

Comment: thanks for replay , it still take many time to convert to mp3 . I think if i can convert the sound to flv by using some library , do you have any idea of using the byteArray to build flv Audio ?